# Can we convert exisiting aws single AZ Fsx to multi-az fsx

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-fsx, multi-az

I have a single AZ aws windows Fsx created with 3 months of data. it was created using terraform.
Can I convert the existing single-az to multi-az without any downtime ?

Any risk involved or DNS changes of Fsx endpoints? Any important points to consider before changing it?

I didn't find any aws KB in this scenario

Comment: Why not test this on some dummy FSx setup?

Comment: Yeah. testing on the POC box. wanted to check in the community for any constraints faced while testing or in production

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link:
[Automate the Upgrade of an Amazon FSx for Windows File Server to a Multi-AZ deployment](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/automate-the-upgrade-of-an-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-to-a-multi-az-deployment/)

The above blog post can assist in understanding the migration workflow and it provides a cloud formation template that automates a lot of the steps involved.

This part of the public documentation provides some details about each migration step: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/migrate-to-fsx.html

But I shall elaborate here as well:

## Risks

#### DNS Alias cut over

There might be slight downtime (few minutes or seconds depending on the TTL of DNS record) when you cut over the [DNS alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/managing-dns-aliases.html)

#### Permissions

NTFS or share permissions could be lost if not cloned over to the multi az correctly. (Use robocopy or AWS DataSync)

#### Configurations

Encryption config if changed from default, would need to be recreated on multi-az along with Volume Shadow Copy and Data de-duplication schedule.

If security audit logs are enabled on single-az, it will need to be re setup on multi-az and pointed to a new CloudWatch log group (the automation in the blog post above takes care of this step as well.)

I trust you will find the above information helpful, please write back if you have any questions.